# how to create an ubercart product content type within a module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I'd like to create a product content type from within a module. I followed [this](http://drupal.org/node/231019) very helpful guide to programmatically create a content type. Now how do I "productize" it?

If there already exists a module that does this that I can use to learn from, please do point me in it's direction. Or perhaps there is a guide floating around somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently, if you're creating a content type that is also an ubercart product class, you cannot simply follow the tutorial that I linked to above and then "tack on" ubercart stuff. According to the tutorial above, you need to implement the following hooks to create a content type from within your module:

- hook_info()
- hook_perm()
- hook_access()
- hook_form()
- hook_help()

To create a content type that is also a product class, you need to make the following modifications to the above list:

- Remove hook_info(). Not sure why this causes a problem, but it does.
- Use hook_perm(), hook_access(), hook_form() and hook_help() as usual.
- Use hook_enable() (which fires when the module is enabled), and include the following code:

  ```
  function uc_yourmodule_enable() {
    db_query("INSERT INTO {uc_product_classes} (pcid, name, description) 
              VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", 
              'product_class_id', 
              'Product Class Name', 
              'Product Class Description.');

    node_types_rebuild();
  }
  ```

As you can see, the snippet adds an entry to the uc_product_classes table, and I guess that's all ubercart needs.

Finally, I've also implemented an ubercart-specific hook further down in my module: [hook_product_types()](http://api.ubercart.org/api/function/hook_product_types/2)

I'm just figuring this out as I go along, so I'm happy to receive corrections or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I was just figuring this out, this seems to work ok, its unfortunate the api doesnt support this in a official way.

```
    function create_uc_product_type ( $name , $pcid , $description )
     {

     $pcid = preg_replace ( array ( '/\s+/' , '/\W/' ) , array ( '_' , '' ) , strtolower ( $pcid ) );


    db_query ( "INSERT INTO {uc_product_classes} (pcid, name, description) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" , $pcid , $name , $description );
    uc_product_node_info ( TRUE );
    variable_set ( 'node_options_' . $pcid , variable_get ( 'node_options_product' , array ( 'status' , 'promote' ) ) );

    if ( module_exists ( 'comment' ) ) {
        variable_set ( 'comment_' . $pcid , variable_get ( 'comment_product' , COMMENT_NODE_READ_WRITE ) );
    }

    module_invoke_all ( 'product_class' , $pcid , 'insert' );

    if ( module_exists ( 'imagefield' ) ) {
        uc_product_add_default_image_field ( $pcid );
    }



    $type = node_get_types('type', $pcid);
    $type->custom = 1;

    node_type_save($type);

    node_types_rebuild ( );
    menu_rebuild ( );

    drupal_set_message ( t ( 'Product class ' . $pcid . ' created.' ) );

}
```